# Request and response queue in iPhone client-server app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http

How to implement a queue which has request and response coming from the server in iPhone client-server app?

I am pretty new to this type and is there any example which I can refer to start up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSURLConnection API. It's a great high level API for managing requests from iOS.

Here's Apple's docs on it, they are very descriptive
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

In general, the programming pattern closely mimics how you would make AJAX requests from JavaScript in a browser.